# How do I turn the file commands into a print statement?

Tags: python, file, web-scraping, printing

```
    page = requests.get('https://free-proxy-list.net/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    text_table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'proxylisttable'})
    body = text_table.find('tbody')

    for row in body.find_all('tr'):
        cols = row.find_all('td')[:7]
        proxies.append({
            'ip': cols[0].text,
            'port': cols[1].text,
            'iso': cols[2].text,
            'country': cols[3].text,
            'protocol': 'https' if cols[6].text == 'yes' else 'http',
            'alive': True})



   with open("proxies.txt","w+") as file:
       [file.write(f"{p['ip']}:{p['port']}\n") for p in proxies]

    os.startfile('proxies.txt')
else:
    print("Socks4, Socks5 Not available yet. Contact --- on --- if you want Socks4/5 in the next update.")
```

Basically, this code writes the scraped information (from the website) to a file. Pyinstaller doesn't support 3.6+ features so I need to adjust the code to make it print the information into the cmd console. Please provide answers that can only be used in 3.6 or below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Added:

```
print(cols[0].text)
```

to body.find_all